# Cakephp v 0.2.9 redirects to javascript

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, redirect

Every time I try to load the main website of cakephp, I get a blank page. I walked through the page and I find that the page redirects.

In dispatcher.php around line 102

```
if (is_array($url)) {
    $url = $this->__extractParams($url, $additionalParams);
} else {
    if ($url) {
        $_GET['url'] = $url;
    }
    $url = $this->getUrl();
    $this->params = array_merge($this->parseParams($url), $additionalParams);
}
$this->here = $this->base . '/' . $url;
```

`$this->getUrl()` returns j`s/fancybox/jquery.jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js`

so cake is trying to find the controller and action to a call to retrieve a js asset. As of right now, I dont know what is causing the redirect. There will be more to come.

I am also getting this error `Non-static method ClassRegistry::addObject() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

I guess its another deprecation issue I have. since I am using cakephp 1.3. Its a older installion. I added the following to cake/bootstrap.php. but still nothing

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: cakephp-v-0-2-9? Thats from 2005. Impossible. Take a look at the VERSION.txt file - there is your real cake version.

Comment: Oops, this is what I am getting 1.3.12. Ive updated my post as well. I am also getting errors. Note, I am migrating this application to a new enviroment.